Is it possible for scenes to be addressables?
I would like to load scenes via asset references, just like other assets.
But SceneAsset belongs to the UnityEditor namespace, so even though I can have AssetReferenceT<SceneAsset> it's not very helpful.
In short, I don't necessarily want to have my scenes to be part of the build's scene list. I'd like the possibility of downloading them like I do other assets.
I have considered packing my levels as prefabs instead, but then I wouldn't be able to use Unity's traditional baked lighting features which are for scenes, to my understanding. I also don't particularly care about asset duplication in this scenario.
I've seen a solution where you pack them into AssetBundles and then load those, but I was under the impression that Addressables was meant as an alternative to directly working with AssetBundles (even though it uses AssetBundles under the hood).

What I managed to do here is to make any desired scene be added to the build list automatically.
I don't know if this would be useful to you. Like a manager where you choose which scenes will be sent to the build (this is possible to do).
